# Integral with $\mathrm{d}y$ in brackets and no variable

Tags: integration, notation, distribution-theory

[Context: page 18, equation (5.4)](http://www.hairer.org/notes/Regularity.pdf)

I'm confused by the following notation:
$$\int D^{(k)}K_n(x-y)(\Pi_x\tau)(\mathrm{d}y).$$
We have that $K=\sum_{n\geq 0} K_n$, where each $K_n$ is a smooth function $\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$.

$\Pi_x \tau:\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a tempered distribution (i.e. some generalised function).

I'm confused by the notation. What does it mean to take an integral, with $\mathrm{d}y$ in brackets? If it said something like
$$\int D^{(k)}K_n(x-y)(\Pi_x\tau)(y)\mathrm{d}y$$
then that would have made more sense to me, but I don't know how to interpret the above expression.

Comment: in theoretical physics, this notation is sometimes used to absorb constants like $2\pi$ into the measure

Comment: To be fair the author does have a background in physics (I think), so it would make sense he'd use 'their' notation. I'll try to figure out the details, thanks @tired